# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when use selector with two args

Tags: swift4.2

It crash inside `runTimer()` because of two args. If I put only one or nothing - it works normal.
Crash forward to AppDelegate and error is

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)

```
var timer = Timer()
var seconds = Int()

@IBOutlet weak var twoMinView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var twoMinLabel: UILabel!

@objc func twoMinTimer() {
        seconds = 120
        runTimer(view: twoMinView, label: twoMinLabel)
}

@objc func runTimer(view: UIView, label: UILabel) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.updateTimer(view:withLabel:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTimer(view: UIView, withLabel label: UILabel) {
    seconds -= 1

    if seconds < 1 {
        view.isHidden = true
        timer.invalidate()

        if view == twoMinView {
            streamView.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    label.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
}

@objc func timeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60

    return String(format: "%02i : %02i", minutes, seconds)
}
```

Comment: What is `withLabel`? shouldn't it just be `label`?

Comment: it could be, but its not influence on result

Comment: So you are saying in update timer that doing `view:label:` makes no difference?

Comment: Exactly this I mean

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `updateTimer` and replace `runTimer` with next one

```
@objc func runTimer(view: UIView, label: UILabel) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in

            if self.seconds < 1 {
                view.isHidden = true
                timer.invalidate()

                if view == self.twoMinView {
                    self.streamView.isHidden = false
                }
            }

            label.text = self.timeString(time: TimeInterval(self.seconds))

            self.seconds -= 1
        })
    }
```